# Firebase onSnapshot state management issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I recently ran into an issue with **firebase (onSnapshot)** realtime updates. The problem is that onSnapshot updates the **state** whenever a document is (created, deleted, updated) which overrides the state.

In other words, let's say I have a variable called state.

```
let state = null;

// And when I visit (**/homepage**) ,,,, onSnapshot runs.

firebase.collection(someCollection).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
   state = (we save documents we got from collection in state variable);
})

// I display these documents on the /homepage.

// Now, I click and call a function (orderByTitle)
// this function gets docs from firebase ... ordered by title.

async function orderByTitle(){
  let docs =  await firebase.collection(someCollection).orderBy("title").get();
  state = docs;      // (it overrides the "state" with docs oredered by title & display on page.
}

// Now, I delete one of the docs.
// The problem starts here as it triggers (onSnapshot) again
// and my ("state" variable) gets override with "unordered docs" again.
```

So, my question is how you prevent (onSnapshot) from overriding your current state or do you manage two different states? And if you manage two different states then how you remove the current elements from the DOM which are using old state and you force them to use other state.

Comment: Part of the essence of Firebase is that your data is kept fresh through events passed to your app. So if something in Firebase changes, and your app is observing for changes, it will be notified of that change - which is the behavior you're describing. What else are you expecting it to do or not do?

Comment: Is there a way to pause (onSnapshot) for sometime and then start is again later?

Comment: If you are not interested in receiving events (which is essentially what you're asking) then `.onSnapshot` is the wrong function to use - `getDocuments` is better. If you just want to read data once then check out the getting started guide [Get Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.onSnapshot` function will update the data each time there's a change in the database which is why `state` keeps changing.

It appears that you want to read the data once. From the docs

> You can listen to a document with the onSnapshot() method. An initial
> call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot
> immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then,
> each time the contents change, another call updates the document
> snapshot

on the other hand, if you want to read data once and not have it continually update use the .get function. Here's an example of getting all documents from a collection once, with no further notifications.

```
db.collection(someCollection).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

More reading can be found in the documentation [Get Data Once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_all_documents_in_a_collection)